# How to enable sorting on a particular column instead disable particular column in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to enable particular columns sorting.

Is there any way to enable particular columns sortable. I would appreciate if you help me out.

Kindly reply me ASAP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
drawingsColumnDefs = [ { "bSearchable": true, "bVisible": true, "sDefaultContent": "n/a", "aTargets": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] }, { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 5, 6 ] }, { "sClass": "txtCentered", "aTargets": [ 1, 2 ] }, { "sWidth": "230px", "aTargets": [ 0, 4 ] } ]
```

and

```
$('#tableID').dataTable({"aoColumnDefs": columnDefinitions})
```

Comment: I Want to enable particular columns. 
If I give { "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 5, 6 ] } I can able to disable sorting for particular columns. But If I give { "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": false, "bVisible": true, "aTargets": [ 5, 6 ] } like this I cannot enable 5th and 6th column alone sortable.

Comment: { "bSortable": true, "aTargets": [ #column indexes ] }